# How to post-process these Blu-Ray files?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion, mp4, m2ts

I have downloaded some video files (MP4) from the web and want to create a BD from them. I've used ConvertXtoHD3 for that, and it does basically a nice job, with menus and all that. Unfortunately the videos play on my BD player (more precise: Panasonic UBC-90, a BD-Recorder with HDD), but fast forward or backward (literally everything except regular playback speed) is impossible.

I suspect that this is a fault of the BD player, which reacts a bit allergic on subtle differences in the file format.

My idea is to post process and replace the .m2ts video files that ConvertX2HD created on my HDD prior to burning the structure to the BD disk.

I've inspected some files with ffprobe, and the stream infos are:

##### Downloaded input file for ConvertXtoHD3

(created with Firefox plugin VideoDownloadHelper, tweaked with current ffmpeg for cuda support)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'xxxx.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.4.101
  Duration: 00:51:55.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2230 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2092 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

##### Same video, written as output by ConvertXtoHD3

(in BDMV\STREAM directory of the BD strcture)

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '00000.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:51:55.71, start: 2.000000, bitrate: 3643 kb/s
  Program 1 
  Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
```

##### A random sample video

(taken from some random BD, written by the Panasonic UBC-90 recorder, which works well)

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '00004.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:51:59.58, start: 6071.678778, bitrate: 7058 kb/s
  Program 10302 
  Stream #0:0[0x1a04](deu): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006) (hearing impaired)
  Stream #0:1[0x1a05]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:2[0x1a06](deu): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
(... some more audio streams ...)
```

Since I'm a bit puzzled by the huge pile of ffmpeg's options, I kindly ask for some advice (i.e. a command line example to try) for coverting the output file of ConvertXtoHD3 to somewhat as close as possible to the file the recorder has written. It would be an acceptable option to just build a conversion from the original MP4 to the BD replacement file if that would be better ... and I'd appreciate even more if the example makes use of my NVIDIA GPU (CUDA).